# iOS: App freezes when start typing in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, ios15

I have a UICollectionViewController and I show the search bar when the user taps on a button. But when the user start typing in the search field the app freezes and the memory starts skyrocking on this line

```
self.collectionView?.reloadData()
```

This is happening ONLY in iOS 15+. All version before that are working like a charm.

Here is my code:

```
//Create search bar

lazy var searchBar: UISearchBar = {
    let sb = UISearchBar()
    sb.placeholder = "Enter search text"
    sb.barTintColor = .darkGray
    sb.tintColor = .darkGray
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = .white
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).textColor = .darkGray
    sb.delegate = self
    return sb
}()
```

When the user taps on a button I add it to the navigation bar

```
   fileprivate func addSearchBar() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(searchBar)
        searchBar.anchor(top: navigationController?.navigationBar.topAnchor, left: navigationController?.navigationBar.leftAnchor, bottom: navigationController?.navigationBar.bottomAnchor, right: navigationController?.navigationBar.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 64, paddingBottom: 4, paddingRight: 64, width: 0, height: 0, centerX: navigationController?.navigationBar.centerXAnchor, centerY: navigationController?.navigationBar.centerYAnchor)
        navigationItem.title = ""
        searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

And when the user start typing the searchBar func is called

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            filteredItems = items
        } else {
            filteredItems = self.items.filter { (item) -> Bool in
                let name = items.name?.lowercased()
                let search = searchText.lowercased()
                return ((name?.contains(search))!)
            }
            if filteredItems.count == 0 {
                emptyCellTitle = "No items found."
            }
        }

        self.collectionView?.reloadData() // the freeze happens here

    }
```

When the

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
```

is removed there is no freeze and the user can type what he wants without problems but the data is not filtered.

Currently I'm out of options. I have tried every solution I found but nothing is working. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated!

Again, this is happening ONLY in iOS 15 and up.
Thanks!

Comment: this line for each "taps on a button" can add to navigationbar? navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(searchBar)
first of issue is that. you must use the line once.

for your issue you must run all filter on other thread and then after finish you must update main thread.

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar this line for each "taps on a button" can add to navigationbar? - No, when the first tap is performed I add the bar, then remove it and so on. There is no duplication at any point. 
Also I tried to run the other solution - searching on other thread and reloading with the main thread but the issue still exists.
The main problem for me is that this is happening only in iOS 15 and later.